# php retrieve all data from db field and store to a file

Tags: php

i have a table called users and a field on it called email

i want to retrieve (all) emails from this field ,then store them in a file

i tried to use while loop,and then i used file_put_contents,but this only save the first column and not the whole data

how can i store all emails retrieved from while loop in a file

```
$data=$db->query("select * from users order by userid desc");

 while($row=$data->fetch_assoc()){
 $string=$row['email'].",";
    file_put_contents("data.txt",$string);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be better off with...

```
$data = $db->query("select * from users order by userid desc");

$emails = array();
while ($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
    $emails[] = $row['email'];
}

file_put_contents("data.txt", implode(', ', $emails));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to move `file_put_contents()` out of the while loop and only call it once when you have collected all the data into a string.

Try this:

```
$data=$db->query("select * from users order by userid desc");

$string="";
while($row=$data->fetch_assoc()){
    $string .= $row['email'].",";
}

file_put_contents("data.txt",$string);
```

**ps:**

If you are appending data to a file (in general), you should use

```
file_put_contents("data.txt",$string,FILE_APPEND);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MySQL inbuilt function to export the data to the file

```
 SELECT * FROM `table_name` INTO OUTFILE /path/file.txt
```

and if you want to import then do like this

```
 LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/file.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

Comment: good solution using sql commands,thanks vineet i use this also with jaitsu answer,appreciated

Comment: @mohamedamin using PHP would be really slow process then inbuilt mysql. Both things are getting the database in text file but we can also mysql file to import data also but PHP data needs extra commands

Answer (score 1):

I think, you want this:

```
file_put_contents("data.txt", $string, FILE_APPEND);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php